# Android - gradle script or function for duplicate maven project repository template

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build.gradle

In my top-level build.gradle file for my Android project, I have to import several maven project repositories. The structure looks like this:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    // How can I avoid this duplicate code block?
    maven {
      url "https://my_maven_project_url"
      credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
        def jobToken = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
        if (jobToken == null || jobToken.empty) {
          name = "Private-Token"
          value = "myAccessToken"
        } else {
          name = "Job-Token"
          value = jobToken
        }
      }
      authentication {
        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
      }
    }
```

url `"https://my_maven_project_url"` and `"myAccessToken"` are the 2 things I need to pass in for each project. Can I write a script or a function that basically does the `maven { ... }` portion as a template and I just pass those 2 values in for each project?

The issue is that I think in a function we would need to create the `maven { ... }` portion programmatically instead of in the template form like shown above, but I may be understanding incorrectly...

Answer (score -1):

You can write method like this

```
ext.myMethod = { param1, param2 ->
        // Method body here
    }
```

and call method

```
myMethod('param1', 'param2')
```

Comment: when I do: `ext.downloadGitlabMavenArtifact = { artifactUrl, artifactTokenKey ->
    maven {`, I get an error `Could not find method maven() for arguments`... i think this is due to inserting the `"maven {...}"` code into the function...?